# When is the induced map in a pullback diagram a fibration?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration, pullback, diagram-chasing

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be topological spaces and let $f:X \to Z$ and $g:Y \to Z$ be continuous. Let $P$ be the pullback of $X\stackrel{f}{\to}Z\stackrel{g}{\leftarrow} Y$. Let $E$ be another space and let $p:E\to X$ and $q:E \to Y$ be continuous, such that $f \circ p = g \circ q$. By the pullback property, they induce a continuous map $h: E \to P$.

My question: If $f$, $g$, $p$ and $q$ are Hurewicz fibrations, can I conclude that $h$ is again a Hurewicz fibration?

Comment: Consider the case when $E$ is a point.

Comment: Thanks! If $E$ is a point, then $X$ and $Y$ are necessarily points, since otherwise $p$ and $q$ could not be fibrations. Going on, one could derive that all spaces in the diagram were points, so the claim would be true for trivial reasons!?

Comment: What definition of fibration are you using?  Serre?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that: Hurewicz fibrations.

Comment: I "retract" (pun not intended) my previous non-helpful comments.

Comment: Try $Z=\ast$ with $X=Y=E$ and $p,q$ the identity maps.